# How can I calculate built in voltage between base-emitter and base-collector, taking bandgap narrowing into account?

Tags: bjt

I understand that if you ignore bandgap narrowing Vbi = kT/q * ln(Nd * Na / (ni * ni))

emitter carrier concentration of 10<sup>20</sup>cm<sup>-3</sup>, base carrier concentration of \$5\times10^{18}cm^{-3}\$ and collector carrier concentration of 5x10<sup>16</sup>cm<sup>-3</sup>. Silicon permittivity is 1.04x10<sup>-12</sup> F/cm.

How can I calculate it when taking bandgap narrowing into account?